# Best APK Audit Tool

Tags: android, security

I am looking for a simple and efficient tool for auditing apk's.

I would like an application that given a APK,

1) obtain the technologies used so that can check the vulnerabilities (cordova version 4.0....), and

2) also follow the flow of the application, I mean, where does the APK stores a file, in what specific directory so that weak credentials could be accessed, check what files does the application leaves when removed...

Those 2 are the highest priorities, then, given the APK or the decompiled code, obtaining other vulnerabilities (SQL injection and other code bugs)

Thank you very much, so far I have come across those websites:

https://apkscan.nviso.be/report/show/e116ec81a40153c222f288a99b6d5860

and

https://mobilesecuritywiki.com/ , where Drozer seems a pretty good one but doesn't seem to meet the requirements of what I am asking for.

Thank you in advance!